# trouble using compass with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass-sass

I am trying to use compass for the first time in my rails app.

compass v. 0.10.5, haml v. 3.0.10

Although I say @import "compass" at the top of my sass file, compass does not seem to get loaded. As a test, I can't use 'border-radius' on a div.

The installation seems to be correct and the files in the suggested places.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Or questions I have failed to ask myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confession of a "duh" moment. I had placed the @import "compass/css3"; command in the partials/_base.scss file and in the screen.scss file said:

```
@import "partial/base";
```

and it should have been:

```
@import "partials/base";
```

I hate it that spelling counts!